# How can I get exact value from list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list `result`. It contains:

```
result[0]
{'id': 'xxxx', 'score': 63.0, 'path': 'frames/212.png', 'dist': 0.0}
```

and:

```
result[1]
{'id': 'xxxx', 'score': 58.0, 'path': 'frames/156.png', 'dist': 8.0}
```

I need to get `score`, `path` and `dist` value from each index. So I imagine it to look like this:

```
>>> result[0].value('score')
```

How can I properly get it?

Comment: why does it "have to look like" `result[0].value('score')` why cant it just be `result[0]['score']`

Comment: Sorry, i am new to Python. I just showed how i imagined this to look like

Comment: Accessing a dictionary's value by key is covered in any introductory Python tutorial, there's a list here: https://sopython.com/wiki/What_tutorial_should_I_read%3F.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need for the .value, in python you can simply do:

```
print(results[0]['score'], results[0]['dist'])

63.0 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

to get all the values you can try a for loop with the get method of a dict class `result = [{'id': 'xxxx', 'score': 63.0, 'path': 'frames/212.png', 'dist': 0.0},`
 `{'id': 'xxxx', 'score': 58.0, 'path': 'frames/156.png', 'dist': 8.0}]`

````
    results = result_list.get('score'), result_list.get(
        'path'), result_list.get('dist')
    print(results)```
````

Comment: Helpful as well. Thank you!